# What is the name of a 3D shape where we polynomially interpret the shape as a set of circles?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I've been playing with ray tracing lately, and in the effort to find a way to represent a torus of genus 2, I made a very stupid miscalculation. My first attempt was to stack the two tori in the x-y plane so that their inner radiuses meet at a point, which leaves an ugly seam.

It has been a long time since I have done much math (please forgive me if I misuse some terminology), and without much thought, I conjectured that I could possibly make a "parabolic radial patch" to get rid of this, which of course didn't work because a torus has circular curvature and not parabolic curvature.

In any case, I ended up creating a shape $S$ defined on an interval $[-a, a]$ which comprises circles starting at $(-a, 0, 0)$ that increase parabolically in radius up to 0, and then decrease parabolically back down to a point at $(a, 0, 0)$, defined as follows:

$$S(a, b) = \{(x, y, z)\ |\ y^2 + z^2 = f_{a,b}(x)^2, x \in [-a, a]\}$$
$$f_{a,b}(x) = -\frac{b}{a^2}x^2 + b$$

(I realize I can remove the restriction $x \in [-a, a]$ and the shape ends up more interesting by expanding outwards again in circles of increasing radius.)

I spent a lot of time implementing this failed attempt at patching the two tori to get a genus-2 torus, and I don't want to throw it away since it seems kind of interesting in its own right.

Does anyone know if this shape has a name or is a specific instance of a more general shape? I can see using shapes other than circles (e.g. squares of increasing side).

Furthermore, I have had little luck coming up with a way to model a torus of genus 2 with ray tracing, and I'd like to do so without using a polygonal mesh. Does anyone know if this can be done with two tori and some positioning and patchwork between them? Apologies for the ambiguity here, but I'm not really sure where to begin the process.

Comment: I don't know if it has a more specific name, but if I understood you well, what you got is a [fusiform (spindle-like) shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusiform), which can also be seen as the [surface of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution) generated by rotating a parabola around the x-axis, constrained to the [-a, a] interval (3D modeling software packages often have tools that let users do this with arbitrary curves - it's variously called revolve/lathe/screw modifier)

Comment: I just looked at some of the examples of fusiforms and that is exactly what it is, and the parabola rotation makes complete sense. Thank you for solving this mystery for me! I wish I could do more than give your answer an upvote.